# Reference movies for mastering

Tags: mastering, loudness, dynamics

What reference movie do you have for mastering? 
I'm more concerned with dynamic range and loudness. Which movies have the best of both worlds?

I think the last Superman movie was too loud, I didn't liked. But Gravity was amanzingly quiet! Have very soft passages but everything is audible. You can hear the room tones in all 5.1 speakers

Comment: The title of your question is a bit misleading. There is no mastering that concerns levels in films per se. That is a common misconception from music folks that have never mixed feature films. So neither a Gravity or Superman was "mastered" level wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like Millenium, the girl with the dragon tatoo.
Very elegant and perfect balance in terms of  loudness.
Music and sound get along very well in a brilliant way.
Brilliant.

Comment: I've seen that one!! Ithought it was pretty good too!!

Answer (score 0):

I really liked Prometheus, the hectic parts just had the right impact!

Comment: Would you mind articulation/clarifying please?  i'm sure details will help benefit the community.  Thanks!

Comment: I really liked the overall balance between Loud and hectic parts and quiet parts. Also the . The movie just felt right from Minute one, which is hard to achieve with a Sci-Fi theme IMo.

Answer (score 0):

The ship and battle scenes from Master & Commander are good references for dynamic range.

Answer (score 0):

Ninja Assassin had a lot of dynamic range, probably a little too much. The gun battles were incredibly loud in comparison to the dialog. I might have made the movie a little more exciting, but I bet a lot of people were riding levels at home with that movie.